# border is not covering the child divs

Tags: html, css

I know that there is already a similar title exists but that wasn't helpful. the border isn't covering all the child div's I have tried giving `height:100%` and as usual it didn't work. I am dropping an image below and in that image, the border suppose to cover all that content. any help is very much appreciated.
[image]

```css
.strategy-card{
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.tile{
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="border" style="height: auto;">
   <h4 class="text-center" style="margin-bottom: 2%;">Students who got answers right</h4>
   <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 text-center tile">
      <p>Correctness</p>
      <div style="display: flex;justify-content: center;">
         <div class="strategy-card col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <p>Right</p>
            <h3>20%</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="strategy-card col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <p>Wrong</p>
            <h3>20%</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="strategy-card col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <p>Unattempted</p>
            <h3>20%</h3>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 text-center tile">
      Dominant Strategy
      <h4>By Elimination</h4>
      <h5> My strategy - Formula/Knowledge</h5>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 text-center tile">
      <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Time Taken
      <h4>1m 02s</h4>
      <h5>My time - 2m</h5>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **the border isn't covering all the child div's** does it mean you want your all text inside of the red border?

Comment: i dont see any border in snippet, nevertheless use `position:relative;float:left;` for div.border

Comment: what's the issue? you want to add border for border class?

Comment: yes i need to wrap everything with border @CodeBug

Comment: @premKumar You also forgot to add the css code for your .border, anyway, in my answer you'll find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a bootstrap class of row to that  like this:
`<div class="row border">`

**DEMO** Run Code Snippet Below

```css
.strategy-card {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.tile {
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px auto !important;
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row border">
      <h4 class="text-center" style="margin-bottom: 2%">
        Students who got answers right
      </h4>
      <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 text-center tile">
        <p>Correctness</p>
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center">
          <div class="strategy-card col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <p>Right</p>
            <h3>20%</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="strategy-card col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <p>Wrong</p>
            <h3>20%</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="strategy-card col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <p>Unattempted</p>
            <h3>20%</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 text-center tile">
        Dominant Strategy
        <h4>By Elimination</h4>
        <h5>My strategy - Formula/Knowledge</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 text-center tile">
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Time Taken
        <h4>1m 02s</h4>
        <h5>My time - 2m</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to your included bootstrap styling.

- you have bootstrap styling
- you have inline styling with flex
- you also have a bit of css at the top.

It might be easier if you use a bootstrap border class. Or don't use bootstrap.